# Modal view controller over Presenting view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, uivisualeffectview

I have a view controller that I am presenting modally over another view controller, and the background view for the top VC has a blur effect. When I am using the following code, the top view controller appears over the bottom view controller, but the top controller is hidden behind the navigation bar:

```
MOSettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[MOSettingsViewController alloc]init];
settingsViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
settingsViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[self presentViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I remove the line `settingsViewController.modalPresentationStyle...`, the new view controller appears over the navigation bar, but the presenting view controller turns black, and ruins the blur effect.

How can I get a mixture of these two presentations, where the presenting view controller stays visible and the navigation bar is under the presented view controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`, I needed to use `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Raedwald I am the author, and by changing that bit of code, it fixed my problem

Comment: Fixed my problems too! When I was using `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`, the in call status bar would appear, but AutoLayout wouldn't work and adjust the view hierarchy. With `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` everything works now as it should!